# Javascript plugin for others to access specific items in my database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apache

I'm looking to create a plugin that people can use on their sites to pull specific reviews from my mysql database, without giving them direct access to my database. These reviews each have a column in the DB for the product # and that's how i want to specify what it should pull.

I've seen similar things where you can get javascript generated to do this. I also don't want to let others that see their websites source code just copy the code and use the reviews on their site.

Example: 
http://www.reddit.com/widget/

`<script src="http://www.reddit.com/.embed?limit=5" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If anybody has some idea of how i could accomplish this, please push me in the right direction. I have looked at RSS feeds a little bit, but don't feel that it is dynamic enough. I have full access to the server (running ubunbtu w/ apache, php, and mysql).

Comment: Have you considered a REST service?

Comment: You can develop a RESTfull service to accomplish that, I found this resource very useful http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Comment: thank you Saquib, if this were an answer id pick it :)